# Removing linefeeds using java

Tags: java

I have a text file with a mix of newlines (CR/LF or `\r\f` or "\n") and formfeeds (LF or `\f`) in a tab `\t` delimited file. The newlines appear as the expected, "\n" but the formfeeds are also used as internal field delimiters. Example:

```
COL_1   COL_2   COL_3    COL_4
1       A\fB    C\fD     2
```

Using Java I was able to remove the formfeeds only after I set `line.separator` to `\r` - for CR/LF or `\r\f` and then reading in the file using the `FileReader.read()` checking for `'\n'`:

```
private void fixMe() throws Exception{

  FileReader in  = new FileReader("C:\\somefile.txt"); 
  FileReader out = new FileReader("C:\\someotherfile.txt"); 

  Syetem.setProperty("line.separator","\r");

  try {
    int c;
    while (( c = in.read()) != -1 ) {
        if ( c != '\n' ) {
             out.write(c);
        }
    }
  }
  ...
```

It appears that `in.read` has a default setting to read "\n" as two characters. I can remove `\f` but now I'll have to write another method to change `\r` to a "\n" and reset `line.separator` as part of the method. Is there a better way to do this? I want to use Scanner, but the solution points at resetting the `line.separator` setting again which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to read all file content, then remove "\n and \r\n and \f", after save where you want.

See example:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path-to-file")));
String processedContent = content.replaceAll("\\n|\\r\\n|\\f", "");
```

Comment: It's a big file, 26K and that would instantiate a 'large' String - have not tried that yet. The other problem is that after replacing (or fixing) all `\f` in the file (or string) will need to add "\n". Don't need to get rid of "\n" where it is `\r\f` but only where `\f` is by itself and add "\n" back where it there is a `\r` for use by Scanner or some other text or regex enabled methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question it seems like you want to skip Line Feed '\f' in the file without skipping if it is CRLF \r\f, so keeping track of last character read might solve your issue.

```
private void fixMe() throws Exception{

  FileReader in  = new FileReader("C:\\somefile.txt"); 
  FileReader out = new FileReader("C:\\someotherfile.txt"); 

//Character 10 'LF' or '\f' and 13 'CR' or '\r'
  try {
    int c;
    int prevCharRead = 0;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1 ) {
        if(c==10 && prevCharRead!=13){
        //it's a line feed LF '\f' without the occurrence of CR '\r' before it, skip it or implement whatever logic you want.  
        }else  
           out.write(c);

        prevCharRead = c;
    }
  }
  ...
```